# JPA 2 CriteriaBuilder Join without relationship

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I want to build a query using JPA 2 CriteriaBuilder:

```
SELECT part_new.*, pn_old.pnumber FROM Part part_new 
JOIN Partnumber pn_new ON part_new.fk_partnumber = pn_new.id
JOIN Partnumber pn_old ON pn_new.pnumber = pn_old.pnumber
JOIN Part part_old ON part_old.fk_partnumber = pn_old.id
WHERE part_old.available=0 AND pn_old.pnumber IN('foo', 'bar')
```

There is no jpa relationship on Partnumber.pnumber, it's just an ordinary string property. (line 3 in code above). Is it possible to build this query using JPA 2 QueryBuilder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it: an implicit join (`cb.equal`) has to be used.

Comment: Too bad you didn't give a bit more code as example... I'm struggling with this myself but your answer is not very helpful.

Comment: Giventhe fact that you have some basic knowledge about JPA criteria queries, I don't know why this answer isn't helpful. Just add a Restriction to your query, checking for equality of the properties you want to join on. Providing a code sample seems useless to me since JPA criteria queries are used in different flavors (with or without metamodel,...).

Comment: I figured it out now. I got that I have to add a `Restriction`, but it is not so obvious that the `cb.equal` needs to combine two different `Root`s. And of course if you already know it, it always seems obvious :)